Erros in Metafields
I have some difficulty in updating an existing metafield with Shopify API. Each time, I received an error, advising me that the variant already exists... so it's not recognized to Update.
I thought this may be an issue with 'put' and 'post' - so changed my method to put, however the error persists. I've hardwired in all my variables to make it easier to test.
I'm working with Cloudinary. I'm using https://github.com/sinechris/shopify-node-api with Express.js
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
  // upload page... assume we have uploaded our image - but have hard-wired a local file in     for now
cloudinary.uploader.upload('/Users/Rob/Pictures/testimg.jpg', function(savedImg) { 
  var imageURL = savedImg.url;
  console.log(imageURL)
},
{
 public_id: "testimg"
});


//  the saved image is returned - so we add it to our updateMetafieldData json object
   var updateMetafieldData = {
   "variant": {
      "id": '253818949',
      "metafields": [
        {
          "key": "variant_image_0",
          "value": 'testimg', // whatever the public id of our image is.
          "value_type": "string",
          "namespace": "variant_image"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
// and post the result to shopify - then redirect to /getvariants
Shopify.put('/admin/variants/253818949.json', updateMetafieldData, function(data){
  // res.redirect('/getvariants')
});

});
advising me that the variant already exists*
